# get total number of rows of a particular class using javascript

Tags: javascript

I hope this should work. But, I don't know why its not working. Actually I'm trying to find the number of rows in a table which are having "active"class .

```
var p_rcd = document.getElementById('tblAllMessages').
        getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].
        getElementsByTagName("tr").                             getElementsByClassName('active').length;
```

getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. Am I going in wrong direction?

Comment: I think getElementxxx methods are defined on `document` object and they are not chainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
 var table = document.getElementById("tblAllMessages").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByClassName('active').length;
  alert(table);
```

Comment: Thank you. But, can you tell me what went wrong in my code?

Comment: The document object is the root node of the HTML document and here you are traversing into each node . From main (document) node to the node having specific id "tblAllMessages" to the node "tbody" and then to the node having class name " active". But in your code your are trying to get a node with classname 'active' inside 'tr' node .

Answer (score 2):

```
var rows = document.getElementById("tblAllMessages").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByClassName("active").length;

alert(rows);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92uuC/

Comment: Got it. Thank you Dastagir :) I've one more question. I'm trying to make one button which is having class as "disabled". But, its not working. Its working for an ID. var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('.nextPage');
   for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i+=1) {
    
    elems[i].disabled = 'true';
   } Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vzmnJ/2710/